# how to call the onbeforeunload in link click event jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the div tag with text box and outside the div I having one link button. * Im using the dataTable js and adding the custom column as "edit" link, its href="#"..

1. If im click on the link without entering any data means it should not call the onbeforeunload function.
2. After entering any data in textbox before clicking the save If im click on the link means it should call the onbeforeunload function. and have to show message like 'You haven\'t saved your changes'.

```html
<div id="inputform">Description
  <input type="text" id="Description" placeholder="Enter the description..." name="description" />
  <input type="submit" value="save"/>
</div>
<a href='www.google.co.in'>link</a>
```

```js
$('#inputform').on('change keyup keydown', 'input, textarea, select', function (e) {
    $(this).addClass('changed-input');
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    if ($('.changed-input').length) {
        return 'You haven\'t saved your changes.';
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4fNCh/809/

Comment: Im using the datatable js.. im adding the custom column in it.. edit link.... That Time it wont work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable ie `saved` to track whether or not the save button was clicked. You can check this in the unload event:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cm8at/1/)

```
var saved = true;

$(function () {
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
        // do the saving...
        saved = true;
    });

    $('#inputform').on('change keyup keydown', 'input, textarea, select', function (e) {
        $(this).addClass('changed-input');
        saved = false;
    });

    $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
        if (!saved) {
            if ($('.changed-input').length) {
                return 'You haven\'t saved your changes.';
            }
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', 'a[href]', function () {
        if (!saved) {
            if ($('.changed-input').length) {
                return confirm('You haven\'t saved your changes.');
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: I want same thing that work for link's href="#"... Thats my problem.... http://jsfiddle.net/4fNCh/809/

Comment: See the updated answer. To do that you can listen on click of all anchors that have a href.